# Find if 2 vectors are equal in python

Tags: python, class, function, vector, python-3.x

Ok so here is my class:

```
class Vec:
"""
A vector has two fields:
D - the domain (a set)
f - a dictionary mapping (some) domain elements to field elements
    elements of D not appearing in f are implicitly mapped to zero
"""
def __init__(self, labels, function):
    self.D = labels
    self.f = function
```

I need help creating a function that takes in two vectors, lets say:

```
u = Vec({'a','b','c'}, {'a':0,'c':1,'b':4})
v = Vec({'A','B','C'},{'A':1})
```

the function equal:

```
equal(u,v)
```

should return:

```
false
```

So far I've tried this:

```
v = Vec({'x','y','z'},{'y':1,'x':2})
u = Vec({'x','y','z'},{'y':1,'x':0})

def equal(u,v): 
    "Returns true iff u is equal to v" 
    assert u.D == v.D
    for d in v.f:
        for i in u.f:
            if v.f[d] == u.f[i]:
                return True 
            else:
                return False
print (equal(u,v))
```

I get true which is incorrect because it's only looking at the last value: 'y':1, how can I check for both?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.  What have you tried?

Comment: My bad @Steve P.  I'll make sure to change my etiquette for now on.

Comment: ok so I've tried this:

`v = Vec({'x','y','z'},{'y':1,'x':2})`
`u = Vec({'x','y','z'},{'y':1,'x':0})`
`def equal(u,v):
    "Returns true iff u is equal to v"
    assert u.D == v.D
    for d in v.f:
        for i in u.f:
            if v.f[d] == u.f[i]:
                return True 
            else:
                return False

print (equal(u,v))`

I get `true` which is incorrect because its only looking at the last value: `'y':1`, how can I check for both?

Comment: edit your post instead of making a comment here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method that you are trying to implement has already been done for you. You can use the set equality and the dictionary equality operator. I ask you not to make a function called `equal` and instead use `__eq__` which allows the use of `==` on class instances.

Here's what you can do

```
def __eq__(self, anotherInst):
    return self.D == anotherInst.D and self.f == anotherInst.f
```

Read about the `__eq__` method in the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

Test Run after applying the changes -

```
>>> u = Vec({'a','b','c'}, {'a':0,'c':1,'b':4})
>>> v = Vec({'A','B','C'},{'A':1})
>>> u == v
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the fields:

```
def equal(self, u, v):
    return u.D == v.D and u.f == v.f
```

Comment: However, if I use:

    `u = Vec({'x','y','z'},{'y':1,'x':2})`
    `v = Vec({'x','y','z'},{'y':1,'z':0})`

I get `True` using that method

Answer (score 1):

I think just implement a function such as `equal` is not the best choice. You can implement the `__eq__` so you can use `==` to identify the similarity.

```
def __eq__(self, v):
    return self.D == v.D and self.f == v.f
```